# HTML submit not sending correct data

Tags: php, html, smarty

My question might seem easy to awnser, however I am unable to find that what I do wrong.

I have my form in HTML as always and my submit button, however, the form is not sending everything. It is only sending a small part of the data.
Here is my form;

```
  <form id="page_access" name="page_access" class="form-horizontal" data-parsley-validate method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="currency">User</label>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <select class="form-control" name="user">
                        {foreach $users as $user}
                            <option value="{$user.id}">{$user.voornaam} {$user.tussenvoegsel} {$user.achternaam}</option>
                        {/foreach}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br/>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Page</th>
                            <th>Index</th>
                            <th>Add</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {foreach $pages as $page}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{$page.nav_name}</td>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" {$page.access} value="page_{$page.id}"></td>
                                {if $page.0.id}
                                <td><input type="checkbox" {$page.0.access} value="page_{$page.0.id}"></td>
                                {else}
                                 <td></td>
                                {/if}
                                {if $page.1.id}
                                <td><input type="checkbox" {$page.1.access} value="page_{$page.1.id}"></td>
                                {else}
                                <td></td>
                                {/if}
                            </tr>
                        {/foreach}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 m-t-20 m-b-40 align-center">
                    <button type="submit" value="page_access" id="page_access" name="page_access" class="btn btn-success m-t-10">
                        <i class="fa fa-check"></i> {$LANG.edit_button}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
```

I use smarty as template engine. All the information generated with smarty is working correctly.

Here is my PHP to catch the data:

```
if($_POST['page_access']){

var_dump($_POST);die;
$settings = new Settings();
$validation = $settings->ValidatePageSettings($array);


if(is_array($validation)){
    $result = $settings->EditPageSettings($validation);
    if($result > 0) {
        $smarty->assign("added_id", $result);
    }
}else{
    $smarty->assign("errormsg", $validation);
}
}
```

My result of this code:

```
array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "2129" ["page_access"]=> string(11) "page_access" }
```

The result I want is to get each page id, with the access 1 of 0.
Instead it will only give back 1 page.

Comment: I think you might want to look at the specification for 'checkbox'; they usually have a shared 'name' tag. Also, what does the variable `{$page.access}` insert in the middle of your checkbox definition?

Comment: The {$page.access} Will output checked if the user already has access to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simple need to add `name` attribute to your checkboxes.

For example, for first checkbox in loop instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" {$page.access} value="page_{$page.id}">
```

You need to have

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_1" {$page.access} value="page_{$page.id}">
                       ^
```

This way data will be send when you click submit button

**EDIT**

That's probably what you want:

```
{foreach $pages as $page}
    <tr>
        <td>{$page.nav_name}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$page.nav_name}[index]" value="1"></td>
        {if $page.0.id}
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$page.nav_name}[add]" value="1"></td>
        {else}
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$page.nav_name}[add]" value="0"></td>
        {/if}
        {if $page.1.id}
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$page.nav_name}[edit]" value="1"></td>
        {else}
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{$page.nav_name}[edit]" value="0"></td>
        {/if}
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Adding the name attribute indeed changed something. However the array returned still is not what it should be. 

I want it to return a big array which contains each page with the value 1 or 0. 

EG: Customers-Index has 1, but customers-Edit has 0.

The current array returned =

     `array(5) { ["user"]=> string(4) "2129" ["index"]=> string(7) "page_21" ["add"]=> string(7) "page_15" ["edit"]=> string(7) "page_19" ["page_access"]=> string(11) "page_access" }`

Comment: What it should be? I don't see any requirements in the question.

Comment: Sorry, but we don't know what are pages, what's their values and what exactly you want to achieve. You need to edit your question and explain in details what you want, probably in new question.

Comment: The array I used to get without the name attribute was<br/>

`array(2) { ["user"]=> string(4) "2129" ["page_access"]=> string(11) "page_access" }`

With the name attribute I get the following array:  


`array(5) { ["user"]=> string(4) "2129" ["index"]=> string(7) "page_21" ["add"]=> string(7) "page_15" ["edit"]=> string(7) "page_19" ["page_access"]=> string(11) "page_access" }`  

However I want it to return an array such as:  


`array(5) { ["user"]=> string(4) "2129" ["index"]=> string(7) "page_21" ["access"]=>string(1) "1" ["add"]=> string(7) "page_15" ["access"]=>string(1) "0"  }`